# No script named 'snapcraft'

Tags: snap

After `apt install`-ing snapcraft, I get this message.  I've tried purging and reinstalling and also installing via `pip3`, but nothing seems to work.  Must be something different with my host because I can install it on a fresh copy of 16.04 without an issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/snapcraft", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('snapcraft==2.26', 'snapcraft')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 719, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1496, in run_script
    raise ResolutionError("No script named %r" % script_name)
pkg_resources.ResolutionError: No script named 'snapcraft'
```

Comment: It happens what ever command I run, even `snapcraft`

Comment: From the output, you're running a copy of snapcraft from `/usr/local/bin`.  This is not the version provided by `apt`.  Perhaps that's your problem?